# How much time is lost in 'Time Keeps on Slippin''

Tags: futurama

In time [*Keeps on Slippin'*](http://theinfosphere.org/Time_Keeps_on_Slippin%27), Farnsworth creates a basketball team which he matures by abusing Chronitons. This leads to time skipping forward by random, but ever increasing amounts.

How much time was skipped in this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think a good estimate can be made for this, for two reasons:

1. Many of the time skips move forward by an indeterminate amount of time.
2. At one point, the Professor mentions localized regions of space skipping forward much more than others. We then see two young boys on the street below complaining about having to pay social security, only to suddenly become senior citizens and start complaining about wanting their money. Thus, each individual could have experienced a different amount of time skippage.